# Or logic operator not working in [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I am trying to filter `Core Data` entities.

When trying to use or `||` logic operator in `NSPredicate`, I get predicate parse error.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "(dRIV_NAMESURNAME CONTAINS[cd] %@) || (vEHI_PLATE CONTAINS[cd] %@)"'
```

When filtering with this, no problem:

```
NSPredicate* preFilter = 
   [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dRIV_NAMESURNAME CONTAINS[cd] %@", strSearch];
```

When filtering with this, no problem:

```
NSPredicate* preFilter = 
   [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"vEHI_PLATE CONTAINS[cd] %@", strSearch];
```

This gives parse error:

```
NSPredicate* preFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
   @"(dRIV_NAMESURNAME CONTAINS[cd] %@) || (vEHI_PLATE CONTAINS[cd] %@)",
   strSearch, strSearch];
```

Comment: try leaving the parentheses out so ```NSPredicate* preFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dRIV_NAMESURNAME CONTAINS[cd] %@ || vEHI_PLATE CONTAINS[cd] %@", strSearch, strSearch];```

Comment: still not working. same error

Comment: The `||` should work in exactly the same way as the compound predicate. Can you verify that you are using the same data & search string (e.g. not a `nil` `strSearch`)?

Comment: not nil. same input works when condition filtered seperatlly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `NSCompoundPredicate` like

```
NSPredicate* filter1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dRIV_NAMESURNAME CONTAINS[cd] %@", strSearch];

NSPredicate* filter2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"vEHI_PLATE CONTAINS[cd] %@", strSearch];

NSArray *searchFilters=@[filter1,filter2];

NSPredicate *compoundPredicate=[NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:searchFilters];
```